# How to reset a customData value in ui5?

Tags: sapui5

I want to change the customData value on click of a button ,i can get the value using oEvent.getSource().data("key") but how to reset it ?

oEvent.getSource().data().key =1

above code doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Remove custom data

```js
oEvent.getSource().data("key", null); // or
oEvent.getSource().removeCustomData(sCustomDataId);
```

Or remove all:

```js
oEvent.getSource().data(null); // or
oEvent.getSource().destroyCustomData();
```

### Add or modify custom data

```js
oEvent.getSource().data("key", data); // or
oEvent.getSource().addCustomData(new CustomData({ // required from "sap/ui/core/CustomData"
  key: "key",
  value: data
}));
```

See [here](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/data).

And BTW: accessing properties like you did with `oSource.data().key` is not recommended. You should always use the getters/setters.